# Is it politically likely that the US and UK will ease bilateral immigration following the UK's withdrawal from the EU?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, european-union, immigration

Gigi Hadid has recently said that the U.K. should change its immigration system, with it being unfriendly to Americans who want to emigrate there. She complained how Americans can't come to the U.K. unless no European or British citizen can fill a job or the spouse earns more than £18,600 ($24,410).

She has said that Theresa May should take advantage of the so-called Special Relationship between the U.K. and U.S. and allow Americans unlimited rights to live in the U.K. like EU citizens currently have.

Gigi Hadid, Alessandra Ambrosio, Martha Hunt and Karlie Kloss are active campaigners on trying to change this rule and have been for the past 18 months now.

Could the EU exit or "Brexit" as some of the blogosphere call it, mean that what Gigi Hadid is saying could happen?

Edit/potential conflict of interest: I am partially employed by Gigi Hadid and Karlie Kloss as a freelancer. Posted here with their permission.

Comment: Is this meant to be unilateral (US citizens have freedom of movement to the UK, but not the other way round) or bilateral (both populations are free to move both ways)?

Comment: Bilateral is what Gigi Hadid referred to.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it desires us to predict the future.

Answer (score 5):

When the UK elects to formally leave the EU it will be necessary to negotiate a large number of trade deals, both with the EU and with non-EU countries. So far a [government department](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_for_Exiting_the_European_Union) under [David Davis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Davis_(British_politician)) MP has been created, but Theresa May has indicated that the formal process will certainly not begin this calendar year.

The current Conservative government is broadly supportive of free trade policies, so is likely to seek low or zero tariff arrangements for goods and services, particularly those involving financial services, which currently form a double digit percentage of UK tax receipts. However freedom of movement, in the sense that EU citizens currently possess it, is a politically difficult issue, which formed the principle basis of a lot of the Leave campaign's material during period before the referendum. While some Leave voters would find English speaking US immigrants more acceptable than those from Europe, there will be many who subscribe to the ideal of "British jobs for British workers".

On the US side, the political calendar is deep in the election cycle and until the presidency and the composition of the senate is decided, it would be wrong of me to guess precisely how such an idea would be viewed, but I'd point out that even Canadians, with whom the US have fairly tight trade relations don't have the relatively liberal bilateral interpretation of existing agreements over freedom of movement and work that EU citizens currently possess. As far as I can tell none of the people you name are political lobbyists, nor running for office, so their expressed opinions as private citizens and minor celebrities is unlike to cause a political movement in favour of more open migration in the US.

The short version is that Brexit probably makes this a tiny bit more likely than otherwise, but I certainly wouldn't hold your breathe or put any money on this.